# Unable to parse XML using XElement

Tags: c#, xml

Baffled as to how hard this is turning out to be.

I have some xml like this:

```
<Wibble xmlns="https://www.example.com">
 <Cat id="abc"></Cat>
 <Dog></Dog>
</Wibble>
```

I want to get the value 'abc'.

I have tried many many things but nothing seems to work.

`var parsedXml = XElement.Parse(xml);`

If I do:

`parsedXml.Descendants();`

This gives me the various descendants, Cat and Dog.

If I do `Descendants("Cat")` I get null.

I don't understand why.

I have also tried using paths with other functions, parsing it as an XDocument, all kinds of stuff, nothing is working. Before I give up and literally regex the damn string out, is there a nice way to do this?

Could someone help?

Comment: XML considers namespaces to be important things. `((XNamespace) "https://www.example.com") + "Cat")` should find your element.

Comment: try using Xpath

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I do Descendants("Cat") I get null.

Because you forgot about your xml namespace `xmlns="https://www.example.com"`

Correct way is:

```
XNamespace ns = "https://www.example.com";
var car = xml.Descendants(ns + "Cat");
```

Comment: Is there a way to get it without the namespace? I don't know what the namespace would be until the XML arrives

Comment: I use this: `XNamespace ns = xml.Root?.Name.NamespaceName;` where xml is XDocument

Comment: hmm, `XElement` does not have a `Root`

Comment: @NibblyPig Always load your XML document as an `XDocument`: `var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlString)`

Comment: Aha, xmlDocument.Descendants(ns + "Header"). works, now I need to get the id attribute out. `.Attributes("id")` did not work ... ah my bad it's case sensitive. That's probably going to be an issue as well, ARGH.

Comment: `xmlDocument.Descendants(ns + "Cat").Attributes().Single(c => c.ToString().ToLower() == "id").Value` boom, simple as that, xml is ridiculous, many thanks for your help

Comment: @NibblyPig if you need only one attribute use `element.Attribute("id")?.Value` (`?.Value` if you need value) method

Comment: @NibblyPig If you want to do a case-insensitive search, it's better to do `c => c.Equals("id", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)` (or one of the other `XXXIgnoreCase` options). Some languages do weird things when changing case (see e.g. Turkish and the dotted/dotless i)